# NSArray Error: NSCFArray objectAtIndex index (5) beyond bounds (5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, runtime-error

I have an MutableArray filled with values from a database:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int n=0; n<[self.array count]; n++) {
    [objectsArray addObject:[[self.array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"Name"]];
    [objectsArray addObject:[[self.array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"Name_En"]];
}
```

I show the values on labels like so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[dic objectForKey:@"d"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[dic objectForKey:@"d"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name_En"];
```

So far the app works fine. It starts without throwing an exception and the values are in the labels. But if I start to scroll the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (5)'
```

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably saying the table that you have 6 rows, but you actually have 5. The reason for this exception is that the table view asks for cell for `indexPath.row` with value of 5, which means it thinks that there are 6 [0:5] rows, but your array in the dictionary has 5 items [0:5).

Comment: and how can i fix this? Because there are only 5 values in the dictionary

Comment: look at the method `–tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` there you must return the number of items in your array.

Comment: i return it like this - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   
    
    return [objectsArray count];
   
    
}

Comment: [objectsArray count] returns how many objects you have in the dictionary, not how many objects has each array for key in the dictionary. Why you use dictionary with arrays inside?

Comment: I have webservice which returning JSON Data so i put the values in a dictionary. How can i count each array for each key in the dictionary?

Comment: What I can see you're setting the cell's data only from one array from the dictionary which is with key `d`. Change the [objectArray count] to [[dic objectForKey:@"d"] count] and it will probably work, but think about a more appropriate solution.

Comment: this works for now, but i will about a appropriate solution. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same the problem which you mention earlier.
Then I did this :-

```
cell.TitleLabel.text=[[AllUserDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0];
cell.DateAndTimeLabel.text=[[AllUserDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1];
cell.InfoLabel.text=[[AllUserDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:2];
if([[AllUserDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] count] >3) {

 NSData *imageData=[[AllUserDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:3];
 UIImage *travelImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 cell.ImgView.image=travelImage;
```

It is working fine and logically correct also(I think so) :)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same the problem and i got the solution:

NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
objectsArray=nil;

for (int n=0; n<[self.array count]; n++) {
    [objectsArray addObject:[[self.array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"Name"]];
    [objectsArray addObject:[[self.array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"Name_En"]];
}
```